# function involving the measure of a set : is this function continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $R^n$ and let $u \in L^{1}(\Omega).$ For $k \in R$ denote $A_k= \{ x \in \Omega ; u(x) > k\}$.

Define

$$ g(t) = |A_t|, t >0 .$$
Intuitively this function is continuous. I have no idea of how to prove this ... and I dont know a counterexample.I am asking just by curiosity. Someone could help me with a proof or counter example?

Comment: What does the notation $|A_t|$ mean? The cardinality, the measure?

Comment: the measure of $A_t$

Comment: Let $u = 1_{[0,1)}$ on $(-1,1)$. Then $g=1_{(-\infty,0)} + 1_{(-\infty,1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = 1$, $\Omega = [0,2]$, and
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
2 & 1 \leq x \leq 2
\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$
|A_t| = \begin{cases}
2 & 0 < t < 1 \\
1 & 1 \leq t < 2 \\
0 & t \geq 2
\end{cases},
$$
which is not a continuous function of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Let $u=0$. Then $g(t)= 0$ for $t\geq 0$ and full measure else.

Comment: I did a mistake in the question. I made a edit

Comment: @johnkurrs Your edit changes nothing just make $u=1$

Comment: Yeah, that's simpler